# What is the unit of Reactor Publisher Timer metrics?

Tags: project-reactor

I am publishing reactor metrics as described in https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_publisher_metrics.

What is the unit of the `[name].flow.duration` Timer metric? Is it nano secs? milli secs?. Is there a way to configure it?

Answer (score 1):

these timers are published in the default unit of Micrometer, nanoseconds. There is currently no way of configuring it, but most metrics backend should be able to perform conversions IIRC